# Car Battery on a 2012 Honda civic used vehicle it started acting up around summer could this be by?

Tags: honda, starting, civic

Hello recently I put in a new battery but every now and then when I turn it on it wont start ill try it 3 times and than it will turn on why is it doing this?

Comment: Is the engine turning? Is there just a clicking sound? Have you replaced any ignition related parts recently?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it's one of the following: the ignition switch, the ignition relay, starter relay or the starter. Do you hear a click when you try to start the car? If yes then your ignition relay and ignition switch are probably OK. Confirm this with a meter: make sure the starter is getting power, should be able to test from the fuse panel. If the starter is getting power and the motor is not starting then you have a bad starter. If there is no power at the starter start tracing to the ignition relay and the ignition switch.